# Chatterbot start a command intead of output string

Tags: python, chatterbot

I see some example code on documentation website of Chatterbot

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

# Create a new chat bot named Charlie
chatbot = ChatBot('Charlie')

trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot)

trainer.train([
    "Hi, can I help you?",
    "Sure, I'd like to book a flight to Iceland.",
    "Your flight has been booked."
])

# Get a response to the input text 'I would like to book a flight.'
response = chatbot.get_response('I would like to book a flight.')

print(response)
```

Is there any possibility to tell the bot to start a command from terminal and not post a string answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `input` if you have python3 or `raw_input` if python2

```
while True:
    question = input("")
    response = chatbot.get_response(question)
    print(response)
```